# issue with time field in filename

Tags: bash, wildcards

```
cd /u01/saddy | printf '%s\n' "XYZ.ABC.V.$(date -d '2020-06-14 +1 day' +%Y%m%d)"*.batch ;
```

When I runthe above command in `putty` by going at path `/u01/saddy` the command is running fine and  gives the output as expected i.e

```
XYZ.ABC.V.20200615180200.batch
```

But when I am trying to run the command from the home location the command returns output as

```
XYZ.ABC.V.20200615*.batch
```

The files at location `/u01/saddy` are:

```
XYZ.ABC.V.20200615180200.batch,
XYZ.ABC.V.20200616190100.batch,
XYZ.ABC.V.20200617140200.batch.
```

Comment: Why would you pipe the "output" of `cd` into a command? That doesn't make any sense. You probably want `cd /u01/saddy; rest_of_the_command`

Answer (score 3):

```
cmd1 | cmd2
```

Is to run `cmd1` and `cmd2` concurrently from two different processes with the output of `cmd1` connected to the input of `cmd2` via a pipe¹

So:

```
cd /some/dir | printf '%s\n' some-glob
```

doesn't make much sense. That changes the current working directory of some (ephemeral) process while at the same time printing the expansion of some glob in the other.

It sends the output of `cd` to `printf`, but first `cd` won't print anything², and anyway `printf` doesn't read its input.

Presumably you meant:

```
cd /some/dir && printf '%s\n' some-glob
```

That is, change the working directory of the shell, and, after, if that `cd` was successful, print the expansion of that glob.

Or (for that `cd` to be done in a separate process and `printf` to be called from that same process after the current directory is changed):

```
(cd /some/dir && printf '%s\n' some-glob)
```

(where `(...)` starts a subshell environment, generally implemented by forking a child shell process, where changes to the environment like that done by `cd` are limited in scope to the inside of those `(...)`).

---

<sup>¹ or *socket pair* with some shells</sup>

<sup>² the only cases where it may print something on stdout is when you pass `-` as argument (or `-<n>`/`+<n>` with  some shells) or a slash-less argument while `$CDPATH` is set.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You have not shown the file content in your "home location", but I assume it doesn't contain any files that match the pattern

```
XYZ.ABC.V.date-time.batch
```

In that case however, the `*` glob will not be expanded by the shell, and instead will be passed *literally* to your `printf` command. That's why you get the output string you describe.

If you want to avoid that, try setting

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

Then, in case that an expression containing a `*` doesn't match anything, it will expand to the empty string rather than containing the `*` literally.

However, you see already from that behavior that the `cd` command the way you use it obviously has no effect. You may want to explain in more detail *what* you are trying to achieve with the command; then maybe contributors can help you find a better solution (the issue about why you use a `|`, e.g., was already raised in a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/596967/issue-with-time-field-in-filename/596969#comment1114308_596967)).